# Tensorflow - Oscillating Learning Rate on CIFAR-10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I edited the TensorFlow sample of [MNIST data set](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros), which got ~90% accuracy on my PC, and tried to use the similar code on [CIFAR-10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html). However the accuracy only ranged from 0-15%, and never got up to 20%.

```
import six.moves.cPickle as cPickle
from pprint import pprint

def unpickle():
  dict=[]
  fo = open(r'C:\train\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_1', 'rb')
  dict.append(cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin1'))
  fo.close()
  return dict

def testpickle():
  afo = open(r'C:\train\cifar-10-batches-py\test_batch', 'rb')
  adict = cPickle.load(afo, encoding='latin1')
  afo.close()
  return adict

dt=unpickle()
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
datadt=np.empty([5,10000,1024])

####to arrange input data properly####
for p in range(len(dt)):
  print(p)
  for i in range(len(dt[p]["labels"])):
    a=dt[p]["labels"][i]
    dt[p]["labels"][i]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    dt[p]["labels"][i][a]=1
    datadt[p][i]=(dt[p]["data"][i].tolist()[:1024])

tdt=testpickle()

###arrange test data properly###
testdt=np.empty([10000,1024])
for i in range(len(tdt["labels"])):
  a=tdt["labels"][i]
  tdt["labels"][i]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  tdt["labels"][i][a]=1
  testdt[i]=(tdt["data"][i].tolist()[:1024])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1024])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1=weight_variable([5,5,1,8])
b_conv1=bias_variable([8])
x_image=tf.reshape(x,[-1,32,32,1])

h_conv1=tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image,W_conv1)+b_conv1)
h_pool1=max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 8, 16])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([16])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 16, 32])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([32])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*16])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([32, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tshaped_x=testdt
tshaped_y=tdt["labels"]
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

k=100
import random
for i in range(len(dt)):
  for u in range(99):
    shaped_x=datadt[i][(u*k):(u*k+k)]#np.reshape(dt["data"][i], (-1,3072))
    shaped_y=dt[i]["labels"][(u*k):(u*k+k)]#np.reshape(dt["labels"][i], (-1,10))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: shaped_x, y_:shaped_y,keep_prob:0.5})
    r=random.randint(0,9000)
    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:tshaped_x[r:r+50], y_:tshaped_y[r:r+50],keep_prob:1.0}))
```

The neural network part of the code is very similar to the sample, however results:

```
0.08
0.06
0.12
0.2
0.14
0.14
0.1
0.12
0.1
0.1
0.04
0.14
0.14
```

(For convenience I just used each picture data RGB's Red data as input - the original 3072 int indicates R,G,B, and i used the first 1024 ints, as shown by `dt[p]["data"][i].tolist()[:1024]`)

I've been looking for answers in different sites but sadly failed. As a beginner to Tensorflow, sorry for being naive. Thanks for your generous help in advance!

**P.S. No matter how I altered AdamOptimizer learning rate from 0.0001 to 999, the results is the same(very similar)**

Comment: I don't really understand your "P.S." note concerning the learning rate. Do you really mean 999 or 0.999? If you really mean 999, I would suggest to try a learning rate that is much smaller, i.e. 0.005.

Comment: @ml4294 yes, from 0.00001 through 0 to 999, results are terrifyingly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initialization of weights, lower the standard deviation, say around 0.01, or tweak with it more. Your network will start to learn then!

Refer to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198840/cnn-xavier-weight-initialization

Keep in mind those are variances given and we need to feed standard deviation so square root those.

Comment: thanks but the results are still the same... any other ideas:(

Comment: Simply reshaping the cifar-10 dataset doesn't work. Try viewing the data, you will notice you have to transpose it for it to make sense. Please post the image you get after respective reshapings. Use matplotlib.pyplot for it.